# Creating Sandbox Accounts Not Working

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When creating sandbox accounts through the developer.paypal.com dashboard, either individually or with Bulk Account Upload, the accounts that should only have a bank account are not created correctly. When I look at the account profile there is an error notice: "We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account. Please delete it and try again." It was the same one that I was getting on all accounts created without a hard enough password. There is no payment methods in the created accounts. I can log into the accounts and they appear to work fine except trying to add payment methods to the "Wallet" does not work. Is there anyway to find out the actual error or get around this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an intermittent issue and clearing cookie and cache on your browser will help.

If the issue still persist, you might need to file a ticket via https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask and provide all the relevant information (e.g: screenshot of the error message, browser information, etc). Their technical support will check this for you.